# Can't find bundle for base name Warn

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, internationalization

ResourceBundle [classpath:/org/springframework/security/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath:/org/springframework/security/messages, locale ru
I can't find any solution for setting internationalization in Java

This is how my code looks like

```
public static final Locale defaultLocale = new Locale("ru");

    public LocaleConfig() {
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new FixedLocaleResolver(defaultLocale);
    }
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rs.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/messages");
        rs.setBasenames("classpath:/org/springframework/security/messages");
        rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
        return rs;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }
```

Comment: Why is there still a slash in your error? Did you copy my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basenames are relative to the root of the class path, you don't have to write it, see [1.15.1. Internationalization using `MessageSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-messagesource):

> ```
> <beans>
>     <bean id="messageSource"
>             class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
>         <property name="basenames">
>             <list>
>                 <value>format</value>
>                 <value>exceptions</value>
>                 <value>windows</value>
>             </list>
>         </property>
>     </bean>
> </beans>
> ```
>
> The example assumes that you have three resource bundles called `format`, `exceptions` and `windows` defined in your classpath. Any request to resolve a message is handled in the JDK-standard way of resolving messages through `ResourceBundle` objects.

Your modified code:

```java
@Bean
@Primary
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource rs = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    rs.setBasenames("org/springframework/security/messages");
    rs.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    rs.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return rs;
}
```